# PostgreSQL GOTO like keyword to jump to a block

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a PostgreSQL function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION increment(i integer) RETURNS integer AS $$
BEGIN
IF i<0 THEN 
RETURN i + 1;
ELSE
  GOTO label1;
END IF
<<label1>>
RETURN null;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

In this function I have to GOTO to a label1, but GOTO keyword is not working, can u please help me in getting the way from which I am able to jump from a particular code to label.

Comment: Why do you need the ELSE branch at all? Your IF branch returns from the function and your ELSE just says "go to the next statement after the IF/ELSE" and that's what it would do anyway.

Answer (score 8):

Another nested Begin block?

```
BEGIN
  <<label1>>
  BEGIN 
      IF i<0 THEN 
          RETURN i + 1;
      ELSE
          EXIT label1;
      END IF;
  END;
  RETURN null;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It seems to work perfectly in my case.

Comment: This is great for (IF) guard clauses.

Answer (score 6):

workaround:

```
<<label>>
LOOP
   ...
   EXIT label WHEN i > 0;
   ...
   EXIT;
 END LOOP label;
 some;
```

But I didn't use it ten years - so usually you do some wrong

Comment: JUMPing are basic sentences in assembly language. And all your IFs or CASEs are converted into GOTOs behind the curtain. The aversion to GOTOs by high level folks come from not knowing the fundamentals of Computer Science.

Comment: @Nulik - the aversion to GOTO stared computer scientist with procedural programming in reaction on issues in Fortran, Cobol, Basic. The GOTO is not implemented in Postgres from religious reasons - the design of AST based interpret doesn't allow it. PL/pgSQL is based on fast AST interpret (doesn't need JIT), but the GOTO is hard to implement. The PCode interprets allows simple GOTO implementation (it is like portable assembler), but requires JIT and it is lot of code and complexity more.

Answer (score 2):

PL/PgSQL does not have GOTO operator.

But, why do you need goto? In your case you can simply remove ELSE and get behavior your are looking for.

Comment: I know GOTO is not working in Postgresql . I have a block of code that I want to skip on a particular condition for that I have to use something like GOTO.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `GOTO`.

`DECLARE` a boolean variable. Set its value based on whether you want to execute the next block or not. Wrap that block in an `IF` that tests the variable. Magic, it's skipped!

I'm assuming your code is cut-down and simplified, because otherwise it'd make no sense. Here's one way to do it, assuming you can't just delete the "ELSE ... GOTO" and let control flow on.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION increment(i integer) RETURNS integer AS $$
DECLARE
    run_condition boolean = 't';
BEGIN
  IF i<0 THEN
    RETURN i + 1;
  ELSE
    run_condition = 'f';
  END IF;
  IF run_condition THEN
    -- Do the optional thing
  END;
  RETURN null;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```