# Jump to another label in a plpgsql function

Tags: postgresql, label, plpgsql

I was developing a stored procedure in Postgres and fell to a situation where I have to access different label blocks depending on the result of my control structures. Is there any possible way of doing this?

Sorry for not providing the code immediately. Here's my concept solution for this problem:

```
BEGIN
    IF LotFlag = 1 THEN
        IF lotno = '' THEN
            RETURN 3;
        ELSE
            SELECT * FROM "DEDGE_im_tblinventory_unposted"
            WHERE "DocRef" = docref
            AND "TranCode" = trancode
            AND "LotNo" = lotno;

            IF NOT FOUND THEN
                /*Go to testblock1*/
            ELSEIF FOUND THEN
                /*Go to testblock2*/
            ELSE
                /*Go to testblock3*/
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END;

<<testblock1>>
BEGIN
    RETURN 1;       
END;

<<testblock2>>
BEGIN
    RETURN 1;       
END;

<<testblock3>>
BEGIN
    RETURN 1;       
END;
```

Comment: You're supposed to provide some code to make it easier for us to give you a relevant answer. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: There is no `GOTO` in plpgsql http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13508190/postgresql-goto-like-keyword-to-jump-to-a-block

Comment: Yes I have actually read that question already. But is there any approach possible where I can jump or access or even run another block of label? Because if were to use `EXIT`, it would just go to the next block of codes without me being able to control it.

Comment: [Ain't no such thing as "postgre"](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Identity_Guidelines). Also, please, *always* include a function header, it is an integral part of any plpgsql function. And your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

Use functions, not "GOTO"

```
        IF NOT FOUND THEN
            /* call f1() or f(1) */
        ELSEIF FOUND THEN
            /* call f(2) or f(2) */
        ELSE
            /* call f3() or f(3) */
        END IF;
```