# Is it possible to implement goto using labels in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, label, goto

This is a sample function. I am not sure how to make the control to reach label1. I see many workarounds with exit from label, but not moving control to the label.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sample(i integer) RETURNS integer AS $$
    BEGIN
    IF i<0 THEN 
    RETURN i + 1;
    ELSE
      label1;
    END IF
    <<label1>>
    RETURN null;
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: PostgreSQL Doesn't Support `GOTO`. So you have to manage it with your `IF`.

Comment: It is not possible to achieve the functionality of GOTO using labels?

Comment: Yes it is possible using if else

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PostgreSQL GOTO like keyword to jump to a block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13508190/postgresql-goto-like-keyword-to-jump-to-a-block)